# Difference between these two ways of declaring, one with new one without?

Tags: go

What exactly is the difference between these two?

```
wg1 := new(sync.WaitGroup)
```

and

```
var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
```

And why does
 `foo(someString string, someChn chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup)`

work for wg1 but not wg2 and

`bar(someString string, someChn chan string, wg sync.WaitGroup)`work for wg2  but not wg1?

Comment: `new` initializes an instance of the passed in type and returns a pointer to it, the other approach just initializes the instance of the specified type, no pointer. `*T` is a pointer to type `T`, that's why one works with foo and the other with bar.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new

Comment: The Tour of Go explains basics of the language very well. It is worth working through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new` syntax initializes a [pointer](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1), so `wg1` is of type `*sync.WaitGroup` rather than `sync.WaitGroup`. This is the same as any other language with pointers, though some modern languages do not have this concept directly. In a nutshell, it's the memory address where the object is stored.

One example use in Go is to pass the someobject into a function and change it, since Go is pass-by-value. Passing `wg2` and operating on it would not change the original `WaitGroup`.